# Spring Roo stackOverflow "getRuleContext" error when starting Roo

Tags: spring, spring-roo

Roos:

Running on Mac OSX using STS 3.2 and Spring Roo 1.2.4, when I start Roo for my project, after considerable delay (5 minutes or more), I will get this:

```
StackOverflowError at org.antlr.v4.runtime.ParserRuleContext.getRuleContext(ParserRuleContext.java:248)
```

After that, Roo seems to run fine and does its updates as expected when I modify a Java class, etc.

This error occurred for me in Roo 1.2.2 and 1.2.3.  It does not seem to otherwise be a problem, so I am tempted to ignore it.  However, does anyone know why I see this, or can anyone suggest what to do to remove it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you get this exception in the IDE only or on the command line as well?

Comment: what jdk version are you using? If you're using jdk 7 try jdk 6 maybe?

Comment: Thanks for asking.  JDK is 7, but this is enterprise system so I can't change it.  I have to make it work the way it is.

Comment: The exception apparently only happens in the IDE.

Comment: I'd check my JAR libs and make sure I don't have conflicting libraries in my Project.

Comment: @CodeChimp - thank you for this suggestion. Which JAR libs do you mean? I failed to mention that Maven is involved.  When I re-start STS and then do a complete clean of the workspace, then choose Maven > Update Project, this often also hangs.  Stopping and re-starting the Maven update at that point will kick off Roo, but typing 'hint' or 'version' at the command line in the Eclipse/STS Roo window then causes Roo to display "Executing <command> <project_name>" and lock up.  I then must force quit STS and start over.  Even deleting the Maven directory /Users/<username>/.m2/ does not work.

Comment: With that added info, it sounds like something is hosed in STS.  I would try re-download and re-install STS in another folder, import the project, and see if you still have the same issue.  After that, I would check Roo from command line (not in STS) and see if it does the same hanging there.  Finally, I would move to the dependencies and make sure there are no conflicts.